# Сравнить два объекта в Javascript

Tags: ajax, javascript, объекты

У меня есть AJAX запрос. Выполняется каждые пять секунд.

```
 $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url:"{{URL::action('GpsController@GPSOnline') }}",
              dataType: 'json',
              // Выводим координаты из 1.php
              success: function(data){
                myCollection.removeAll() ;

               console.log(data); 
                  var a = data;

                  if (a.length > 0) {

                     for (var i=0;i<a.length;i++) {  
                            var ch = a[i].ch, poz=a[i].poz, la = a[i].la, lo =a[i].lo;
                            var img = "/../../../images/poz.php?ch="+ch+"&poz="+poz+"&rnd="+poz;
                            console.log(img);
                            ymaps.option.presetStorage.add("my#customIcon"+ch+poz, {
                            iconImageHref: img,
                            iconImageOffset: [-12, -12],
                            iconImageSize: [34, 34]  
                            }); 
                            myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark( [la, lo],{iconContent:"" }, {preset: "my#customIcon"+ch+poz}, {draggable: true});                         
                            myCollection.add(myPlacemark); 
                            b = myCollection  ;
                    }}

                    myMap.geoObjects.add(myCollection);

                        function getZoom(){
                        if (document.getElementById('checks').checked==true){
                        // Автомассштаб
                        myMap.setBounds(myMap.geoObjects.getBounds()); } 
                        else  {
                         }
                        }
                        getZoom();

                } ,
                      error: function(){
                      alert('AJAX заспрос не отработал!');
                            }
                });          
         }
```

Как мне передать значения из объекта myPlacemark в объект `b` и сравнить их (одинаковы они или нет)?

Comment: вы хотите рекрсивно сравнить свойства двух объектов или что ?

Comment: да мне надо сравнить 2 объекта рекурсивно

Answer (score 2):

Для сравнения двух обьектов в Javascript не существует специальных операторов или простых способов.

Но вы можете воспользоваться замечательной библиотекой [underscore](http://underscorejs.org) вам нужна функция [_.isEqual](http://underscorejs.org/#isEqual)

Answer (score 0):

Существует поверье что сравнивать объекты - это моветон (в JS точно, где почти всё - объект, про другие ЯП не знаю, но вряд ли это хороший тон).
Просто из-за того, что это бессмысленно.
Обычно сравнивают несколько полей, если это объекты запроса и на этом хватит.
Если очень хочется, то можно пройтись по объектам `for..in` и сравнить ключи и значения. Правда нет гарантий - свойства могут быть с флагом `DontEnum`.
Но обычные объекты (не встроенные) и достаточно простые (без назначений скрытого флага через `Object.defineProperty`) можно проверить.
Флаг (не `DontEnum` :)) в руки!

Answer (score 0):

Написал для себя небольшую функцию для сравнения объектов. Используется у меня для верного реагирование на изменение параметров в файле настроек. Присылает в качестве результата отличающиеся параметры из newObject. Если в newObject свойство отсутствует, а в oldObject есть, то это тоже будет отображено.

```
/**
 * Compare objects and return properties that are differ
 * @param  {Object} newObj Properties from this object will be returned
 * @param  {Object} oldObj Object to compare with
 * @return {Object}        Object with differ properties
 */
function compareObjects(newObj, oldObj) {
    'use strict';
    var clone = "function" === typeof newObj.pop ? [] : {},
        changes = 0,
        prop = null,
        result = null,
        check = function(o1, o2) {
            for(prop in o1) {
                if(!o1.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;
                if(o1[prop] instanceof Date){
                    if(!(o2[prop] instanceof Date && o1[prop].getTime() == o2[prop].getTime())){
                        clone[prop] = newObj[prop];
                        changes++;
                    }
                }else if (o1[prop] && o2[prop] && "object" === typeof o1[prop]) {
                    if(result = compareObjects(newObj[prop], oldObj[prop])){
                        clone[prop] = "function" === typeof o1[prop].pop ? newObj[prop] : result;
                        changes++;
                    }
                }else if(o1[prop] !== o2[prop]){
                    clone[prop] = newObj[prop];
                    changes++;
                }
            }
        };
    check(newObj, oldObj);
    check(oldObj, newObj);
    return changes ? clone : false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Лучше сделать, чтобы сервер присылал только изменения, а не полные объекты.

А для сравнений - рекурсивная функция, которая сравнивает на равенство, если непримитивные элементы не равны (по ссылке), то вызывает себя рекурсивно. Если примитивные объекты не равны, либо свойства нет в объекте, то всё. Не забыть пройти по свойствам второго объекта и проверить их наличие в первом.

Если есть уверенность, что при одинаковых значениях сервер вернёт одинаковый json, можно где-то сохранить ответ сервера в виде строки и сравнивать их.